# Post to database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code that collects first and second name of the person signing up and these work great.

```
$first_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['first_name']));
$last_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['last_name']));
```

However i also wanted to use woocommerce and the names i have collected i want to input them into the database for the billing address, without having to ask for them twice, so far i have this, but i think its wrong.

```
$first_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['first_name']));
$last_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['last_name']));
$first_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['billing_first_name']));
$last_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['billing_last_name']));
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign it to **different php variable**, because you are assigning same variable twice($first_name,$last_name).